# Strange Import Error in PyDev Eclipse for Custom Classes

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev

Hi I'm trying to write a program in python using Eclipse and PyDev. I have a project structure like this:

[image]

"Root", "GeneralClasses" and "UserClasses" are three directories containing python modules named "FileA", "FileB" and "FileC" and as it's clear there are three classes named "ClassA", "ClassB" and "ClassC".

I was trying to import "ClassA" in "FileC" and I got import error. I tried multiple ways:

1. `import ClassA`
2. `from FileA import ClassA`
3. `from FileA import *`
4. `from GeneralClasses.FileA import ClassA`
5. `from GeneralClasses.FileA import *`
6. `from Root.GeneralClasses.FileA import ClassA`
7. `from Root.GeneralClasses.FileA import *`

All of them gave me the same error. I don't know how to solve the problem. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: I should add that IDE can detect all the classes. I use "ctrl + click" on their names and it leads me to the right place. Additionally, I have import problem in all files for all classes; so it seems there is something wrong with IDE's settings and the code is doing well.

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated your scenario and have the same problem.
Perhaps you did the same thing I did and put your own Root folder in place? (I suspect this because PyDev calls it src.)
You'll need to have the src folder be added to the python path, which PyDev conveniently does for you. All you need to do is: `File > new > other > PyDev > source folder`

more information here http://pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html

Place those files in the src directory and the importing should work fine.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Robin, I added all sub-folders to the python-path and now I can access all classes by importing their files; like `import FileA` and then use `FileA.ClassA`.

Comment: That's good that it works, but try having pydev add ONLY the Root (i.e. src) folder to the path. Then all of the subdirectories will be searched for imports too. Much simpler.

Comment: I tried it. Actually it was right there when I had the problem. Adding sub-folders solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the PyDev view in Eclipse?

If you're editing Python code in a different view, the context menu has an option to create a new "folder" instead of a "python package".  For folders, Eclipse doese not autogenerate an **init**.py file.  As a result, the python interpreter doesn't see the folder as a subpackage.